# Geopandas [Shapely] spatial difference: TopologyException

Tags: python, shapely, topology, geopandas

I'm using the overlay function to intersect two shapes with geopandas :

```
intersection = gpd.overlay(shape1, shape2, how='intersection')
```

But i have this error message :

***TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING***

I thought it was a numeric precision problem so i have converted my shape into geojson and used this function (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217789/geopandas-shapely-spatial-difference-topologyexception-no-outgoing-diredge-f) :

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
def around(geom,p):
    geojson = mapping(geom)
    geojson['coordinates'] = np.round(np.array(geojson['coordinates']),p)
    return  shape(geojson)
shape1.geometry= shape1.geometry.apply(lambda x: around(x,2))
```

But when im using it, i have a new error message :

***TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'***

Comment: gonna be really hard to help you with this if you don't provide the geometries that are causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You get this message, because you had multigeometries in GeoSeries. Instead of an 1D coordinates array you are trying to round list of 1D arrays.

I adjust around function to cover that issue.

```
def around(coords, precision=5):
    result = []
    try:
        return round(coords, precision)
    except TypeError:
        for coord in coords:
            result.append(around(coord, precision))
    return result
```

Then I set up next function which is used as GeoDataFrame apply function

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping

def layer_precision(geometry, precision=5):
    geojson = mapping(geometry)
    geojson['coordinates'] = around(geojson['coordinates'],precision)
    return shape(geojson)
```

As follows:

```
gdf.loc[:,"geometry"] =  gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda x: layer_precision(x, precision=5))
```